# Is it possible to enforce a policy on Windows so users can't build containers, and can only run containers that are in a private registry?

Tags: docker, security, policies

I work in a Government department which has particular security policies.  I want Docker (and Minikube) deployed on local desktops, but our IT department will only allow this if it's possible to deploy Docker in such a way that users can only run containers that are in a private container registry, and are also unable to build new containers themselves (though for this latter point I might try and argue that users should be able to build their own images as long as the base container is from the private registry).  IT will be responsible for building and accrediting containers in the private registry.

I don't have access to a Windows machine that I can install Docker on, and I haven't been able to find an answer in the Docs so I'm hoping somebody can help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: Docker mostly doesn't have any controls on its API; if you can run any `docker` command at all, you can run any image, build custom images, run images as any user, and mount arbitrary host directories into containers.  Isolating Docker inside a VM (as minikube does) helps this a little bit, but there's not an out-of-the-box way to configure the Docker daemon for this.

Comment: Bugger.  That's a shame.  I wonder if we can just modify the Docker bundle so the build command isn't even present...